# Load views - Error with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbie with codigniter, I'm doing a menu, so I put all the links not in the same main file for not repeat all time.

My code is:

In the main.php

```
    <?=$this->load->view('headers/menu');?>
```

In the menu.php

```
    <span><a href="<?=base_url()?>main/agregar">Agregar</a></span> 
    <span><a href="<?=base_url()?>main/modificar">Modificar</a></span> 
    <span><a href="<?=base_url()?>main/eliminar">Eliminar</a></span> 
    <span><a href="<?=base_url()?>main/buscar">Buscar</a></span>
```

So, the following error appears and I don't know why... 
any ideas??? Thank you so much

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: views/main.php
>
> Line Number: 15
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\everisgas\application\views\main.php Line: 15
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\everisgas\application\controllers\main.php Line:
>   9 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\everisgas\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Answer (score 17):

This can be about the version of your framework. For example in CI 2.6

```
    <?php echo $this->load->view('headers/menu');?>
```

works but in CI 3.0

```
    <?php $this->load->view('headers/menu');?>
```

is the usage.

Comment: This was my issue when upgrading from CI2 to CI3. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

if you want to load the content of the view and print it, then you have to tell CI to return the view content as a string, by passing the 3rd parameter as `true`, if you dont set the 3rd parameter to TRUE it will return the CI_Loader instance for the purpose of chaining.

```
<?=$this->load->view('headers/menu', '', TRUE);?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using like below in your main view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('headers/menu'); ?>
```

This will load your menu view file in main view file.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you echoing `<?=$this->load->view('headers/menu');?>`

instead of doing this load it in your controller before loading main view or use `include 'menu.php'` if `main.php` and `menu.php` in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
<?=
```

because it is the same as

```
<?php echo
```

But $this->load->view return **not** a string, so you just need to use

```
<?php $this->load->view('some_template');?>
```

without **echo**!

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter version 1.5.4(or lower) using load->view('headers/menu');?> will load the view file but in Codeigniter version 3.0 this wont work anymore instead you simply use like this load->view('headers/menu'); ?>

Answer (score -1):

you can makey your coding like this

```
<?php $this->load->view('vadmin/menu'); ?>
```

this is can solve your problem

Comment: Please explain your solution