# Object of class error in Codeigniter with loading function in array

Tags: codeigniter

On my Welcome controller I have a function called `content_top` which loads function `$this->$part[0]($setting_info);` in this case `$this->slideshow($setting_info);` Then it should display that slideshow functions view in that data array.

When I have refreshed my page I get a error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string
Filename: common/content_top.php
Line Number: 7
Backtrace:
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\application\views\common\content_top.php
Line: 7
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 51
Function: view
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 19
Function: content_top
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

**And**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string
Filename: common/welcome_message.php
Line Number: 3
Backtrace:
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\application\views\common\welcome_message.php
Line: 3
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 20
Function: view
File: C:\wamp\www\cms\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Question Is there any way to when I have a function in array to be able to make it display the view with out throwing error.

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('design/model_layout');
        $this->load->model('extension/model_module');
        $this->load->model('design/model_banner');
        $this->load->model('tool/model_image');

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->content_top();
        $this->load->view('common/welcome_message', $data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }

    public function content_top() {
        if ($this->uri->segment(1)) {
            $route = $this->uri->segment(1) .'/'. $this->uri->segment(2);
        } else {
            $route = 'common/home';
        }

        $layout_id = $this->model_layout->get_layout($route);

        $data['modules'] = array();

        $modules = $this->model_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'content_top');

        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            $part = explode('.', $module['code']);

            if (isset($part[1])) {
                $setting_info = $this->model_module->get_module($part[1]);

                if ($setting_info) {
                    $data['modules'][] = $this->$part[0]($setting_info);

                }
            }
        }


        return $this->load->view('common/content_top', $data);
    }

    public function slideshow($setting_info) {
        static $module = 0;

        $data['banners'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_banner->get_banner($setting_info['banner_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['banners'][] = array(
                'banner_image' => $this->model_image->resize($result['banner_image'], $setting_info['width'], $setting_info['height'])
            );
        }

        $data['module'] = $module++;

        $data['resize_errors'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors();

        return $this->load->view('module/slideshow', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove True in here `$string = $this->load->view('common/content_top', $data, true);` as well as this will not execute  `return $string;`

Comment: @Abdulla now throws error `Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string`

Comment: You wrote two functions in two different methods !!, When CI load only one for the view

Comment: I have removed all the true from view() but still get blank page just as you can see in image slideshow part not showing on row div.

Comment: To get data to index function,  you have to return data not to load view. This should be `$this->load->view('common/content_top', $data);` change to `return $data`

Comment: Tried $this->load->view('common/content_top', return $data); `Parsing Error`

Comment: This is wrong `return $data);` remove load view part and just paste `return $data`

Comment: Array to string conversion error now showing

Comment: How you returning data??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92630/discussion-between-wolfgang1983-and-abdulla).

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `$this->$part[0]` method in Welcome class that requires `$setting_info` argument? Errors are turned on as well?

Comment: @Tpojka It gets the slideshow function name and vairable no errors showing just as in image does not show correct it is hidden for some reason

Comment: @Abdulla all working now.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 happy to hear :) +2 ;)

Comment: In `content_top()`, why is not checked `if ($this->uri->segment(2)) {` since if only first segment is checked it doesn't still mean next line have to be correct. In other words, you can check first segment and without second segment `$route = $this->uri->segment(1) .'/'. $this->uri->segment(2);` line won't work as expected.

Comment: I will be adding check later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved

On the controller I had to change a couple things around

I also have had to use a template layout to minimize the views

But on content_top and sideshow function I had to use return and true

`return $this->load->view('folder/name', $this->data, TRUE);`

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('design/model_layout');
    $this->load->model('extension/model_module');
    $this->load->model('design/model_banner');
    $this->load->model('tool/model_image');

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}

public function index() {
    $this->data['title'] = 'Home';

    $this->data = array(
        'column_left' => $this->column_left(),
        'column_right' => $this->column_right(),
        'content_bottom' => $this->content_bottom(),
        'content_top' => $this->content_top(),
        'page' => 'common/home'
    );

    $this->load->view('common/template', $this->data);
}

public function column_left() {
    $route = 'common/home';
    
    $layout_id = $this->model_layout->get_layout($route);

    $this->data['modules'] = array();

    $modules = $this->model_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'column_left');

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $part = explode('.', $module['code']);
        
        $setting_info = $this->model_module->get_module($part[1]);
        
        $this->data['modules'][] = array (
            'module_name' =>  $this->$part[0]($setting_info)
        );
    }

    return $this->load->view('common/column_left', $this->data, TRUE);
}

public function column_right() {
    $route = 'common/home';
    
    $layout_id = $this->model_layout->get_layout($route);

    $this->data['modules'] = array();

    $modules = $this->model_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'column_right');

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $part = explode('.', $module['code']);
        
        $setting_info = $this->model_module->get_module($part[1]);
        
        $this->data['modules'][] = array (
            'module_name' =>  $this->$part[0]($setting_info)
        );
    }

    return $this->load->view('common/column_right', $this->data, TRUE);
}


public function content_bottom() {
    $route = 'common/home';
    
    $layout_id = $this->model_layout->get_layout($route);

    $this->data['modules'] = array();

    $modules = $this->model_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'content_bottom');

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $part = explode('.', $module['code']);
        
        $setting_info = $this->model_module->get_module($part[1]);
        
        $this->data['modules'][] = array (
            'module_name' =>  $this->$part[0]($setting_info)
        );
    }

    return $this->load->view('common/content_bottom', $this->data, TRUE);
}

public function content_top() {
    $route = 'common/home';
    
    $layout_id = $this->model_layout->get_layout($route);

    $this->data['modules'] = array();

    $modules = $this->model_layout->get_layout_modules($layout_id, 'content_top');

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $part = explode('.', $module['code']);
        
        $setting_info = $this->model_module->get_module($part[1]);
        
        $this->data['modules'][] = array (
            'module_name' =>  $this->$part[0]($setting_info)
        );
    }
    return $this->load->view('common/content_top', $this->data, TRUE);
}

/*

    Add function for modules that are enabled for this page

*/

public function slideshow($setting_info) {
    static $module = 0;

    $this->data['banners'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_banner->get_banner($setting_info['banner_id']);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->data['banners'][] = array(
            'banner_image' => $this->model_image->resize($result['banner_image'], $setting_info['width'], $setting_info['height'])
        );
    }

    $this->data['module'] = $module++;

    return $this->load->view('module/slideshow', $this->data, TRUE);
}

}
```

**Template View**

```
<?php $this->load->view('common/header');?>

<?php $this->load->view($page);?>

<?php $this->load->view('common/footer');?>
```

**Content Top View**

```
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) {?>
    <?php echo $module['module_name'];?>
<?php }?>
```

**Home View**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $content_top;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Proof Working

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the CI when you loading the view and printing as a string then need to pass the third parameter as 'TRUE'.

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('headers/menu', '', TRUE);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the **echo** on view page when you are using CI new versions.

```
<?php $this->load->view('headers/menu');?>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675633/2790502

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I did this:

```
$model = $this->load->model('user_model);

$data = [
    'model' => $model
];
```

instead of this:

```
$this->load->model('user_model);

$model = $this->user_model->edit();

$data = [
    'model' => $model
];
```

then when I echoed out the `$model`, it gave me the error. So I tried to `print_r` then it gave me a very long array until I realize my mistake. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just trying to help others who have my problem